# Selenium dismiss/accept Chrome confirmation popup window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently automating one of daily processes and I got to the point where chrome popup window appears:

[image]

I've tried to:

```
alert = browser.switch_to.alert
alert.dismiss()
```

Stacktrace:

```
C:\...>python "C:\\...\\script.py" username pwd code

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61324/devtools/browser/464b40f5-dc5b-4fec-be25-35fdadb765e5
[14564:15520:0904/092015.725:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [09:20:15.725] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\script.py", line 53, in <module>
    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
  File "C:\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.8.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 55, in alert
    alert.text
  File "C:\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.8.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\alert.py", line 67, in text
    return self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "C:\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.8.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.8.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

I've tried using `time.sleep(2)` but that didn't helped.

Is there other way of detecting this window? Or in this case we can pass ChromeOptions allowing launcher to be opened and so to prevent this window.

Any help is appreciated.

My code (I'm beginner to this):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time
import sys

url = "link"
argv = sys.argv[1:]

if argv and len(argv) == 3:

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="...\\chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)

    if browser.title == "the_title":

        # Login

        time.sleep(2)
        
        username = browser.find_element_by_name("field1")
        password = browser.find_element_by_name("field2")
        security_code = browser.find_element_by_name("field3")

        username.send_keys(sys.argv[1])
        password.send_keys(sys.argv[2])
        security_code.send_keys(sys.argv[3])

        submit = browser.find_element_by_id("submit")

        submit.click()

        # Detect

        time.sleep(5)
        detect = browser.find_element_by_id("detect_button")
        detect.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        # stuck at this point
        alert = browser.switch_to.alert
        alert.dismiss()
        #WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(lambda d: browser.switch_to_window(str(d.window_handles)))

        # steps after
        ...

    else:
        print("Failed to load the page")

else:
    print("Invalid/Incorrect arguments passed. Provided arguments: " + str(argv))

browser.quit()
```

Comment: What error you got when ran your code without switch to alert ? If you are getting any error except UnhandledAlert then it is not an alert.

Comment: @rahulrai I get no errors

Comment: Then it’s not an alert window. Now Inspect this window and search for //iframe in element tab. See if there is any match.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to accept an alert box would be:

```
browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: I still get the ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert``` with your code.

Comment: Then it seems to be that the webdriver is not even able to recognize the alert box

Comment: Could there be it's not even ```alert``` box type?

Comment: That is most likely the case

Answer (score 0):

On the webpage whenever alert comes, we need to check that whether it is actually a alert or it is just a part of page itself. That you may check by inspecting the alert,

if the alert is not allowing you to inspect it that means it is alert. In this case,

```
alert = browser.switch_to.alert
alert.dismiss()
```

these commands run, if the alert takes time to come then use explicit wait over here

For eg:

```
alert = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
print(alert.text)
# alert.accept()
alert.dismiss()
```

these will work just import `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC` and `from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait`

but if you are able to inspect it and look for the attributes it has, that means it is not a alert, you have to handle the part of page like other elements.
As per the error you are getting `NoAlertPresentException`, this clearly informs there is no alert.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog cannot be handled from within selenium as javascript - it's not a part of web page but a chrome GUI (system dialog). This is the reason why you get NoAlertPresentException.

To skip such exception you may use try-except block:

```
try:
    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
    alert.dismiss()
except NoAlertPresentException:
    print("There's no alert on the page...")
```

Such approach allows you to continue in page processing without exception.

To handle system dialogs you could use some GUI modules like `PyAutoGUI`, `win32api`+`win32con` (like `win32api.mouse_event(win32con..MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y)`) etc. Example with PyAutoGUI to click on button of confirm download dialog on full-sized chrome browser window:

```
import pyautogui as pag  
...
try:
    alert_obj = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert_obj.accept()
except NoAlertPresentException:
    w, h = pag.size()
    pag.moveTo(5*w//9, h//5)
    pag.click()
```